# Testing the python code using non-ascii characters

Tags: python

We are working on migrating a Python 2 code to Python 2&3 compatible code.

We are using futurize for the migration process.

Well, as we all know, there are a lot of issues of Unicode and byte string across the Python 2&3 compatibility. For now, we have only tested the code with simple English characters (ASCII characters)

How can we unit/functional test the methods to check that it won't break when non-ASCII characters are provided as input?

```
def any_random_method(some_string):
    # Some code
    return some_return_string
```

How should I unit test this with non-ascii characters.? A code snippet would be a great help.

p.s I am very confused with how to provide the non-ascii characters specifically to even start the unit testing. and... I want to unit test it with Python 2 and Python 3 both. so the unit test should support both of the versions to handle the non-ascii characters while testing

**Edit**:

- What is the general practice to test the methods with multiple ascii & non-ascii characters.?

Comment: Will unicode work for you?

Comment: Can you elaborate the question a little bit more?   a little clarification: The method can have interaction with rest endpoints as well as with Python's built in functions. So, it can contain bytes and Unicode both. We are making sure each byte string are converted into Unicode first. And at the end, while outputting, we are making sure it is encoded to bytes. Let me know if you need more clarification

Comment: what are the types for your methods argument, only string?

Comment: No, I have just put a sample snippet. The goal is to test any methods working with strings.. I can pass strings as argument or I can even mock the objects. The issue is with how to provide non-ascii characters in those methods.  To simplify, let's assume we have string arguments and want to test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import unittest


def func1(my_string):
    # your code
    pass


def func2(my_string):
    pass


class TestNotBreakFunctions(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.string_utf8 = 'Όταν λείπει η γάτα, χορεύουν τα ποντίκια.'

    def test_func1(self):
        try:
            func1(self.string_utf8)
        except Exception as e:
            self.assertTrue(False, e)

    def test_func2(self):
        try:
            func2(self.string_utf8)
        except Exception as e:
            self.assertTrue(False, e)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

the example is base on the assumption that you have one argument of type str but you can use any kind of arguments, just use try except

Comment: it gives me a syntax error in Python 2.7. `SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xce' in file try.py on line 16, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details`. That's actually where I was stuck. Please let me know how to work with this in Python2. Thanks,

Comment: @JayJoshi just add # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- to your first line, I will update my answer

Comment: It did solve the error.  Can you please suggest, how did you decide to go with the string you mentioned as `string_utf8` .? What different strings should I provide.? From whare can I find the list of characters.? And, what is the general testing practice.? Thanks.

Comment: to have an easy to get utf8 string (not just ASCII characters) you can choose some sentences from languages that have special characters, in this example I chose greek,  you can choose also french, german, russian  etc

Comment: Cool. Is there any OS specific requirement that I should be aware of.? For example, Is there any language that I should have been installed in my windows machine to do that.? Or.. without any configuration, I can perform testing.?

Comment: Just perform your tests

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing string from above solution:
Take a non-ascii string :  'Όταν λείπει η γάτα, χορεύουν τα ποντίκια.'

1. get output of function_abc in python-2 code: let's say "xyz"
2. make unitTest explained as above.
3. Run unitTest on python 3
4. Check that output of function is same as in python-2 code

class TestNotBreakFunctions(unittest.TestCase):

```
def setUp(self):
    self.string_utf8 = 'Όταν λείπει η γάτα, χορεύουν τα ποντίκια.'

def test_abc(self):
    result= function_abc(self.string_utf8)
    self.assertEqual("xyz",result)
```